# tensorflow map_fun indexing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the tensorflow map function but I am stuck at an indexing problem.

In simple python, I am trying to do the following operation:-

```
for i in range(1,25):
      u [i] = uold [i] - K * ( uold [i] - uold [i-1] )
```

In tensorflow, I am encountering an indexing issue due to "(uold1[i]-uold1[i-1])". Currently I have written the statement as:-

```
 u = tf.map_fn ( lambda u: uold - K * ( uold - uold ), uold )
```

In the current equation the second term is always zero. I am not sure how to change it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a tensor that shifts to right by one dimension (using [tf.pad()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pad)) instead, and then calculate the difference.  Ex.

```
temp = uold_shifted_to_right - K * (uold - uold_shifted_to_right)
```

Then take out the first column from temp (using [tf.slice()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#slice)).

Comment: I did something like this:-
u0 = tf.map_fn(lambda a: uold0[1:]-U*dt/dx*(uold0[1:]-tf.slice(uold0, [0], [24])),uold0)
u0 = tf.pad(u0, [[0,0],[1,0]], "CONSTANT")

Comment: however, it's printing the output shape as (25,25). I need it to be (1,25). I'm not sure why it's copying the same matrix into every element.